# Dotfuscator - External type not found System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations.AnnotationValues,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I want to obfuscate my *.exe file and it's dependencies. I received this error:

```
External type not found System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations.AnnotationValues,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: *And its dependencies*? You're not trying to obfuscate .Net dlls do you?

Comment: No, I ignore .Net dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Entity Framework to version 6.2 for primary project and it's dependent projects, and problem resolved.